# Regular Expression Split

Tags: regex

I have a string as mentioned below. I have been trying  to split using regular expression and going through the forums, I found ([^|]+) which would match everything except (pipe) However I want to break this into two using regular expressions, but not been able to do this. So one expression would be (xyz) which would extract from GA till everything before the pipe character, the second would be (abc) which would extract anything after the first pipe.

GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914|3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298

Comment: can you put your expected output?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: If you just want to split at the pipe character, why do you need a regular expression? Use `.split()` in Javascript or Python, `explode()` in PHP, etc.

Comment: The expected output for first regex would be GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914 and for the second would be 3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298 . The reason why it needs to be regex, is because the tool I am using only accepts regex. This regex would split the string and push this into two fields on the fly, or else everyday, a manual dump would be taken and then pushed into those relevent fields. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is `^[^|]+` and the second is `[^|]+$`.

The idea is to use your negated character class with anchors. `^` will match the string start and `$` will matchthe string end.

These two patterns have no lookarounds and will work with almost any regex flavor.

Comment: I think you nailed it down pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing at popular languages. :-)

Python:

```
'GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914|3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298'.split('|')
```

JavaScript:

```
'GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914|3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298'.split('|')
```

PHP:

```
explode('|', 'GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914|3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298')
```

Go:

```
strings.Split("GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914|3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298", "|")
```

Ruby:

```
'GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914|3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298'.split('|')
```

Comment: R:  `strsplit('GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914|3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298','|',fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

After clarification, I get what you're asking. Fiddling with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gC7fX9/1), I found that those two expressions should give you what you want:

`^.*(?=\|)` gets the first part, and
`(?<=\|).*` gets the second.

When you click on the link, you can see it in action.

### PREVIOUS ANSWER

Many alternatives to regular expressions as @smarx's answer reveals.

But something along those lines should do it:

### R

```
myString <- 'GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914|3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298'
part1 <- sub(pattern = "(.*)\\|(.*)", x = myString, replacement = "\\1")
part2 <- sub(pattern = "(.*)\\|(.*)", x = myString, replacement = "\\2")
```

`R` requires doubling all backslashes, some other languages don't.

### Python

```
import re

myString = 'GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914|3847EFF358ABEC90-01A39B0290BAC298'
part1 = re.sub(pattern="(.*)\|(.*)", repl = "\\1", string = myString)
part1 = re.sub(pattern="(.*)\|(.*)", repl = "\\2", string = myString)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, however I need to use only Regex as my tool onlyaccepts regex.

Comment: Those _are_ regexes. It's all more or less the same across languages, or even in text editors like Notepad++... Unless you're talking about the form "/pattern/replacement/", as in `SAS` for instance? What is the tool you're referring to?

Comment: I am talking about Adobe Analytics Classification Importer tool. It is a web based interface. Yes, regex would be same across all platforms. So I have to write one regex (ABC) which would extract only GA1.2.1127630839.1468526914, For this one. I had thought ^GA.*$\| but this one is not working similarly I want for the other one. Same for the other part of the string

Comment: Ah! Now it's clearer what you're after. So, the first one would be `^.*(?=\|)`, and the second one `(?<=\|).*`

Comment: Thanks, great this works perfectly. Regex always has been a nightmare for me. Is there any way I can become half as good as you guys.

Comment: :) You're welcome. Yes there is a way: spend as much time as we did trying (and often failing), you'll get there! The regex101.com site is a wonderful tool to practice and learn, too. Pls don't forget to accept the answer (green checkmark), as it gives both of us rep points!